# Modify multiple XTick values at once

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I want to make a matrix of scatterplots in Matlab (version R2014b), and have only two ticks (minimum and maximum) for each x and y axis because the real world example has more plots and that will be easier to read. Here is an example, and as you can see, the second for loop isn't working as intended to edit the ticks. Also, is there a way to set this without a for loop?

```
% Example data
        example =    [   -5.2844    5.0328  307.5500
  -12.0310    5.1611  237.9000
  -15.9510    7.5500  290.7600
  -11.5500   13.6850  285.8400
   -1.9356    9.4700  273.2600
   -9.2622    4.7456  232.6000
   -6.5639    5.2272  265.3800
   -4.4795   14.8320  281.1300
   -2.1474   13.0690  288.7300
   -3.7342   11.7450  265.2200
  -11.9040   10.9660  286.5700
   -2.1789    6.7442  258.9700
   -2.8316   11.8210  281.7500
   -2.6170    7.4740  244.8600
   -6.8770    1.6623  116.9800
  -10.2210    5.7575  300.2200
   -3.9430    5.9715  253.6000
   -3.3690    5.6530  230.9700
    2.6090    3.2750  236.8700
   -5.1430    8.4060  273.9600
   -7.9360    2.7855  254.8200
   -2.8665    2.0241  176.0600
   -0.0960    3.3165  228.6800
   -8.8465   10.3240  289.2100
   -8.1930   16.4070  289.7000
   -6.5840   13.4010  283.2600
    2.2405    8.4625  270.1000
   -2.2505    7.5555  285.9100
   -4.6955    6.2985  279.2000
   -0.7610   12.5210  283.2000
   -0.7510    9.9470  279.9100
    1.7120    8.5990  285.5700
   -0.6245    7.6905  251.9100
  -19.2320    6.8545  306.2700
   -4.1255    9.8265  298.2000
    2.9486    3.8881  250.2100
    1.7333    5.5000  240.7300
   -6.5881    3.9152  234.3800
   -7.9543    8.0771  276.8000
   -6.9641    8.8573  284.2800
  -10.3280    7.4768  291.8700
   -8.0818    5.1250  250.6600
  -10.1490    3.9427  271.0000
   -2.7786    3.7673  213.6500
  -14.5410   11.1500  288.9100
   -6.8118   11.0210  280.2000
   -2.6459    6.5127  213.2600
    1.4036    4.2023  253.9400
   -5.0014    9.3900  267.0600
   -9.7382   12.0990  290.8800]

% Labels for data
data_labels = {'Variable1','Variable2',...
    'Variable3'};

% Make scatterplot matrix with histogram on diagonal
figure()
[H,AX]= plotmatrix(example(:,:));

% label the axes of the plots (rotated) works fine
for i = 1:length(AX)
    ylabel(AX(i,1),data_labels{i},'Rotation',0,'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
        'FontSize',12);
    xlabel(AX(end,i),data_labels{i},'Rotation',60,'HorizontalAlignment','right',...
        'FontSize',12);
end

% Set ticks (not working yet)
NumTicks = 2;
for i = 1:length(AX)
    L = get(AX(i,i),'XLim');
    set(AX(i,i),'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks));
    % set y ticks here too
end
```

Comment: You need to use `AX(i)` instead of `AX(i,i)` in your last loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly using `i` or *both* subscripts when indexing into `AX`.

```
AX(i)   % Rather than AX(i,i)
```

Also, it's better to use `numel` than `length` and use a variable rather than `i` as your loop variable (since that's a MATLAB built-in for `0 + 1i`). Also, you can use a single linear index into `AX` rather than specifying row and column subscripts.

```
for k = 1:numel(AX)
    L = get(AX(k),'XLim');
    set(AX(k),'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks));
end
```

If you want to do this witnout a loop, you could technically do it using `cellfun` and the fact that you can set the same property in multiple plot objects using the following syntax

```
set(array_of_plot_handles, {'Property'}, array_of_values_to_set)
```

So applied to your problem, it would be something like

```
% Get all XLims as a cell array
oldlims = get(AX, 'XLim');

% Compute the new xlims
newlims = cellfun(@(x)linspace(x(1), x(2), NumTicks), oldlims, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Now set the values
set(AX, {'XTick'}, newlims);
```

Or if you really want it to be one line

```
set(AX, {'XTick'}, cellfun(@(x)linspace(x(1),x(2),NumTicks), get(AX, 'Xlim'), 'UniformOutput', false))
```

Comment: The cellfun works beautifully! In your edits to the original 'for' loop it still isn't quite right... maybe because get(AX(i,i)... needs updating?

Comment: Great comprehensive examples +1